# How do Roles work in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, permissions, admin, nosql

I would like to know how database access roles work in Mongo DB.  The 10 gen page below gives ample details on what the rights of each role are but I don't how to implement them.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/

Do I need to add each role to my database? or is it already added?

***Edit***

I understand adding roles to users.  However I don't see how the roles can be added to specific databases.  I see the following warnings after I have added the user with any of the "default" roles :

warning: No such role, "dbAdminAnyDatabase", in database db1. No privileges will be acquired from this role

Comment: First result on Google: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-to-database/ second: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/ third: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

User privilege `roles` in MongoDB are granted to `users`.  Users may have multiple roles, and may have different roles on different logical database.  As at MongoDB 2.4, authentication is disabled by default and you must explicitly [Enable Authentication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) and add credentials for an administrative user.

If you want to grant a user access to broader roles that apply to [**any** database](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#any-database-roles) (eg. `dbAdminAnyDatabase`) you need to grant these roles in the `admin` user database.  In your example where you received an error, you were trying to grant the `dbAdminAnyDatabase` role via database `db1` instead of the `admin` db.

The MongoDB manual includes a tutorial with examples of adding to specific databases as well as the `admin` database:

- [Add a User to a Database](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-to-database/)

It's worth noting that the available roles/privileges have significantly more granularity in MongoDB 2.4 than previous versions.  The available [user privilege roles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/) are currently pre-defined, but future versions of MongoDB may allow user defined roles -- watch/upvote [SERVER-8580](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8580) in the MongoDB issue tracker for this feature request.

Comment: [User-defined roles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authorization/#user-defined-roles) (SERVER-8580) were added in MongoDB 2.6.